# Rewrite .htaccess - part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/?load=/browse
www.mydomain.com/?load=/files
www.mydomain.com/?load=/search
```

How can I rewrite them to

```
www.mydomain.com/browse
www.mydomain.com/files
www.mydomain.com/search
```

I tried with these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?load=/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

But no luck.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1--Redirect  "/?load=/foo" to "/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?load=/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NE,L,R]
#2--Rewrite "/foo" to "/?load=/foo--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?load=/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works excellent for the first level of url's, but second give me 404

So if I have 

    mydomain.com/?load=/browse/documents

after using rewrite rules you posted, it's redirected to 

    mydomain.com/browse/documents

But it gives me not found/404

Any idea?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes,it is because of the regex pattern in the last rule, it ignores a request with **/** , I have changed the pattern to catch-all , see the edit

Comment: Ah, excellent, I appreciate the help and the explanation. If I may bug you for just a bit of your time. I have two mistakes that I would also like to fix. 1. Rules that you posted translate "[" and "]" characters to "%5b". I would like to keep them as "[" . 2. Rewrite "_" (underscore) to "-" (hyphen). If it's not too much hassle. Tnx

Comment: @Ah0dev I have added a **NE** no-escape flag to the first rule, with NE flag special characters in the uri wont change to hex. and Please ask a new question on Stackov for your 2nd question in the comment.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help and input. Best regards!

Comment: can I add the exception in rewrite rule for images(gif, jpg, png)? If there is an .gif, .jpg or .png at the end, don't rewrite?